# extract the row of data from the first occurance of a unique ID for a set interval of time in R

Tags: r

This is a large data set but here is an example:

```
CollarID, DateTime,             X,            Y    
12450,   6/15/2014,   2400930.319,   1725003.01
12450,   6/15/2014,   2401080.891,   1725085.449
12450,   6/15/2014,   2401061.067,   1725083.886
12450,   6/16/2014,   2401067.087,   1725082.833
35302,   6/20/2014,   2351514.766,   1732670.932
35296,   6/21/2014,   2287266.877,   1647129.914
```

As you can see, there are multiple unique `CollarID`s and some of those `CollarID`'s have multiple locations everyday.

I need to write a code that extracts the first location of the day for each unique `CollarID`. Not every collar has a location everyday.

For example: I need to keep the location from 
`Collar ID 12450` on `6/15/2014` and `6/16/2014`
while discarding all of the other locations from `6/15/2014`.

The result would look like this:

```
CollarID, DateTime,             X,            Y    
12450,   6/15/2014,   2400930.319,   1725003.01

12450,   6/16/2014,   2401067.087,   1725082.833

35302,   6/20/2014,   2351514.766,   1732670.932

35296,   6/21/2014,   2287266.877,   1647129.914
```

I've tried several time with `lubridate`, but I can't seem to get the result I'm looking for. 
Any assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to `slice` the first row of each element you've used in `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(CollarID, DateTime) %>%
       slice(1)
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: CollarID, DateTime [3]

  CollarID  DateTime       X       Y
     (int)    (fctr)   (dbl)   (dbl)
1    12450 6/15/2014 2400930 1725003
2    35296 6/21/2014 2287267 1647130
3    35302 6/20/2014 2351515 1732671
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you could use `duplicated` (assuming your data is sorted by CollarID and DateTime).

```
dat[!duplicated(dat[1:2]),]

  CollarID  DateTime       X       Y
1    12450 6/15/2014 2400930 1725003
4    35302 6/20/2014 2351515 1732671
5    35296 6/21/2014 2287267 1647130
```

Comment: great solution! but shouldn't it be `dat[!duplicated(dat[1:2]),]` to return first occurrence of each CollarID on each DateTime? As written would just return first occurrence of each CollarID. I would edit but can't make the 6 character min...

Comment: It may well be - I wasn't sure if OP was asking for just the first day of any unique ID, or any unique ID/Date.  Will edit.

Comment: Another option is `unique` with `by` option from `data.table`

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure that this worked. However, now I have a file with all of the duplicated data. How do I go about removing those records from the original without an indices?